# Retrieve user input not working?

Tags: javascript, html

So my dilemmna is that I don't know how to record what the user inputs. (my goal as of now is to simply print what the user enters in an input box, not to add the numbers)

```
var x = document.getElementById('textboxone').value;
```

Why isn't this working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html> 

<head> 
<link href="cssFiles/ttt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script Language ="JavaScript">


//create skeleton divs
function createDivs () { 

    var s;


    s = '<div class="simplebox" id="divBody">Bla  3 bla</div>';   
    document.write(s);

}


//create body skeleton
function createBodyDivs (sID) {     
    var s;  
    s = '<div class="smallerbox" id="divInput">';
        s += '<div id="textboxone"><span>Add <input type="text"  ></input></span></div>';
        s += '<div id="textboxtwo"><span>To    <input type="text"  ></input></span></div>';
        s += '<div id= style="margin-top: 100px;"><span> Click here to find the answer! <input type="button" value = "Answer Generator" OnClick="(this.form)"></input></span></div>';



    var oDiv = document.getElementById(sID);

    oDiv.innerHTML = s;
}
//adding the two numbers from input boxes
function addnumbers(form){
var x = document.getElementById('textboxone').value;
alert(x)
}


</script>
</head> 


<body>

<script Language ="JavaScript">
   createDivs();
   createBodyDivs('divBody');
</script>


</body> 



</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post a jsFiddle

Comment: Because you're doing 

    getElementById('textboxone');

'textboxone' is not the input, it's the div.
So you should add that ID to the input tag like or just get the input tag itself like so:

    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)** my friend! :)

**[JSFIddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/sht6j7hc/)**

```
<div ng-app="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message" />
     <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    <div class="{{data.message}}"></div>
</div>
```

using: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly checked the code and first of all you input button will not trigger addNumbers(form) since the onclick of the input doesn't point of that function.

Then for the function itself, `document.getElementById('textboxone').value` returns undefined because the actual value you want is in the `<input>` and not in the `<div id="textboxone">`

So if you have you're createBodyDivs function modified so that the id where on the input, then this `document.getElementById('textboxone').value` would actually return the correct value.

```
function createBodyDivs (sID) {     
    var s;  
    s = '<div class="smallerbox" id="divInput">';
        s += '<div><span>Add <input type="text" id="textboxone" ></input></span></div>';
        s += '<div><span>To    <input type="text" id="textboxtwo" ></input></span></div>';
        s += '<div id= style="margin-top: 100px;"><span> Click here to find the answer! <input type="button" value = "Answer Generator" OnClick="(this.form)"></input></span></div>';



    var oDiv = document.getElementById(sID);

    oDiv.innerHTML = s;
}
```

For the click binding, you button should be the following for it to work:

```
<input type="button" value = "Answer Generator" OnClick="addnumbers()"></input>
```